# Access an element by matching its "html()" content

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, children

I'm working with a `table` `form` which displays the rows of a database table.
There's a unique row with `id=0` which must not be deleted but I'm not able to reach it. The `id` is stored inside a `td` and the `.html()` jQuery method `returns` exactly the `id` (0). The problem is there are many other `td`s in each row with the same value. The only column where the value is unique is the second on the table and I'm accessing it by using `:nth-child(2)`. Here's the table structure:

```
<table class="formTable">
  <tr>
    <th width="26"><input id="chkAll" type="checkbox"
                    onchange="chkSelectAll()"></th>
    <th width="48">Id</th>
    <th width="288">Description</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>MaxTime<br>(min.)</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** I've already got the row number. Now I just need to check if the "td html()" equals to "0".

Comment: can't you set a css class on your second row ?

Comment: Please add a bit more of your code. You are asking for second `td` child of `td`, but don't show any `td` elements in your html.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus Rows are generated dynamicly by loading them from the database. The row I'm looking for does not appear always in the same position so I can't reach it by using a fixed index.

Comment: @Michael_B Same I told him. Rows are generated with javascript, so there are no tds at the beginning.

Comment: You can look at the generated html and share that can't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced selectors in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/
So you can use $('td:nth-child(2)') for example.

Comment: Yeah, I've just got there. Now I gotta get to know which td has 0 for html().

Comment: How about something like if($('td:nth-child(2)').html() == '0') ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Here's the code:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) == '0' }).parent().children().eq(0).children().eq(0).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

This accesses every second td inside a tr, restricts the selection to the one having a "0" as text, gets its parent, access his chilren row which contains the checkbox and this one itself and disables it. Hope this is useful for someone else.